# How to print string in 7th column by reading csv cell value backwards using awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed, csv

I have 7th column with values like:

```
OS:J:\output\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Security.evtx
OS:J:\output\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\System.evtx
```

I want to extract information by reading values backward and put in a new column.

Values to be extracted in a new column, lets say "location" should look like:

```
Location
Security.evtx
System.evtx
```

Comment: What exactly do you want, everything after the last `\`? What is the relevance of "7th" column in this question?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'\' '{print $7}' inputfile
```

Comment: It might be useful to replace `$7` with `$NF`.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but the request was specifically for the seventh field, and so what's what I provide.

Answer (score 0):

As checked Last column is $7 Used below command to extract the values

command

```
sed -r 's/.*\\//g' filename
```

output

```
Security.evtx
System.evtx
```

Comment: `sed 's/.*\\//' file` is sufficient, because * is greedy. Why -r?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are at least six more fields that you don't show preceding the 7th field with the data in the question, you may read the CSV file with a tool such as [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to create a new `location` field for your new values.

Assuming further you have headers in your CSV file (since you want to create a new `location` field) and that the header for the 7th field is `filepath`, then you could do the following:

```bash
mlr --csv put '$location = sub($filepath,".*\\","")' file
```

The `sub()` function would remove all text before the last backslash in the `filepath` field.  The result of that operation is then assigned to the new `location` field.

Testing:

```bash
$ cat file
A,B,C,D,E,F,filepath
1,2,3,4,5,6,OS:J:\output\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Security.evtx
1,2,3,4,5,6,OS:J:\output\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\System.evtx
```

```bash
$ mlr --csv put '$location = sub($filepath,".*\\","")' file
A,B,C,D,E,F,filepath,location
1,2,3,4,5,6,OS:J:\output\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Security.evtx,Security.evtx
1,2,3,4,5,6,OS:J:\output\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\System.evtx,System.evtx
```

```bash
$ mlr --c2p --barred put '$location = sub($filepath,".*\\","")' file
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| A | B | C | D | E | F | filepath                                                | location      |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | OS:J:\output\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Security.evtx | Security.evtx |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | OS:J:\output\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\System.evtx   | System.evtx   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Would you want to make the change in-place, then add the `-I` option before `--csv` on the command line.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk -F ' / ' '{print $7} yourfilename
```

Comment: notice [the existing awk answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522235/117549)...